# Use "full" context variables for AWS APIGW in Serverless Offline

Tags: serverless-framework, serverless-framework-offline

We have a use-case where we need to fetch the API key name from the request to APIGW.

Looking in the logs for APIGW I can see the value in `API Key ID` in `event.requestContext.identity.apiKeyId` but this is not included in Serverless Offline.

Is there any way to include attributes in the `invoke` (Request) somehow or would I need to alter the module code?